# How to return array in coco?

Tags: syntax, coco

The following function returns an object in [coco](http://satyr.github.com/coco/):

```
->
  a: "1"
  b: "2"
```

The next will result in multiple statements and returns the result of the last one (as expected):

```
->
  "a"
  "b"
```

How to return an array without using brackets? I was trying this:

```
->
  * "a"
  * "b"
```

However now it also compiles again into multiple statements.

Is it possible now in coco?

@matyr: Or will it be possible?

*UPDATE*: I am currently using following syntax, but it is not so clean:

```
-> []=
  "a"
  "b"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just on whatever case someone comes on this, this is totally valid :

```
->
 * a
   b
```

Comment: + Thx. It has few chars less:)